# .NET Maui Custom Handlers not working, official docs is wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, maui

I am making an app using .NET MAUI and I am trying to implement custom handlers for specific instances of controls (ex. some entries should use a custom handler I created). To achieve this I followed the official MS [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize) for this. The following is the setup they tell me to use:

1.First make a subclass of the Entry control:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

namespace MyMauiApp
{
    public class MyEntry : Entry
    {
    }
}
```

2.I then customize the EntryHandler to perform the desired modification to MyEntry instances:

```
using Microsoft.Maui;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics;

namespace MauiApp1
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.EntryMapper[nameof(IView.Background)] = (handler, view) =>
            {
                if (view is MyEntry)
                {
#if __ANDROID__
                    handler.NativeView.SetBackgroundColor(Colors.Red.ToNative());
#elif __IOS__
                  handler.NativeView.BackgroundColor = Colors.Red.ToNative();
                  handler.NativeView.BorderStyle = UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.Line;
#elif WINDOWS
                  handler.NativeView.Background = Colors.Red.ToNative();
#endif
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

PROBLEM: This gives me the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0021  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
> 'IPropertyMapper<IEntry, EntryHandler>'   MyMauiApp (net6.0-android),
> MyMauiApp (net6.0-ios), MyMauiApp
> (net6.0-windows10.0.19041)    C:\Users\xxxxxx\source\repos\MyMauiApp\MyMauiApp\App.xaml.cs    24  Active

As I said I followed the docs completely but still this error. I have read that other people have this issue too. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems some breaking changes have been made in this area by the means of this pr [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/1859) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/2458).

From what it looks like this has been done so that you can cascade customizations in mappers with `AppendToMapping` and `PrependToMapping` or modify the whole mapping altogether with `ModifyMapping`.

Without explaining all the variations here, let's focus on your situation. This means that instead of this line `Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.EntryMapper[nameof(IView.Background)] = (handler, view) =>`

You should now declare this as: `Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.EntryMapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(IView.Background), (handler, view) =>`

Note that you should now add a `)` on the closing bracket too, making the full code:

```cs
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.EntryMapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(IView.Background), (handler, view) =>
{
    if (view is MyEntry)
    {
#if __ANDROID__
        handler.NativeView.SetBackgroundColor(Colors.Red.ToNative());
#elif __IOS__
        handler.NativeView.BackgroundColor = Colors.Red.ToNative();
        handler.NativeView.BorderStyle = UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.Line;
#elif WINDOWS
        handler.NativeView.Background = Colors.Red.ToNative();
#endif
    }
});
```

I will see if I can update the Docs here and there and hopefully this won't break again ;)

*Edit:* Updated the [wiki page](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Customizing-Controls-with-Handlers) for this